# Is there any whereIn query in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to find all the users whose phone number is contained in the list.
It's like searching `*` from database where email IN phone_numbers.

This is what I am doing.

```
fun getUsers(persons: List<Person>?): Single<List<User>> {
    return Single.create({ emitter ->
        try {
            val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            val userCollection = db.collection(USER_FIREBASE_TABLE)
            var query: Query? = null
            persons?.forEach({ person ->
                query = if (null == query) userCollection
                        .whereEqualTo("phone", person.phone)
                else query!!.whereEqualTo("phone", person.phone)
            })
            query?.get()?.addOnCompleteListener({ task: Task<QuerySnapshot> ->
                emitter.onSuccess(task.getResult().toObjects(User::class.java))
            })
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace()
            emitter.onError(exception)
        }
    })  
}
```

As you see I am appending **whereEqualTo** each time to the query. Is there any way to replace it with something like **whereIn** and I pass an array or collection of values to match to?

Comment: @Alex Mamo, now wherein is supported in firestore : https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries

You can also chain multiple where() with equal operator ex.:

```
citiesRef.whereEqualTo("state", "CA").whereEqualTo("state", "CO");...
```

Additionally, you can only perform range comparisons (<, <=, >, >=) on a single field:

```
citiesRef.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("state", "CA").whereLessThanOrEqualTo("state", "IN")
```